# Object Reference is not set to an instance of an object error in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  protected void ImageButton_enable_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)    
    {
        foreach(GridViewRow gvrow in GridView_enable.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk1=(CheckBox) gvrow.FindControl("CheckBox_select");
            if (chk1.Checked == true)
            {
                Label lblEmail = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("Label1");
                string email = lblEmail.Text;
            }
         }           
    }
```

What is wrong in my code? i am getting this error "Object Reference is not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see exactly where in the code the null reference occurs?  Presumably one of the controls in your FindControl calls doesn't exist, but the debugger can tell you for sure.

Comment: What line is giving that exception, there are multiple lines in your cod with possible exception.

Comment: On which line? What have you done to diagnose the problem so far? (I suspect one of your `FindControl` calls is returning `null`, but we don't know which, and we don't know why...)

Comment: Which line are you getting that error on? My guess is one (or both) of those `gvrow.FindControl` calls is returning `null`.

Comment: You should really use the debugged to find out which line the exception occurs on, you will then see something is `null`

Comment: No research effort -- paste the error message into google and you would know why -- then you could step thru in the debugger to know where

Comment: if (chk1.Checked == true) this line ...

Comment: @SantanuMaulik chk1 is giving you null; it can't find "CheckBox_select"

Comment: @SantanuMaulik the context of your code is not clear. But if you identify your tags with IDs and runat="server" can't you reference controls directly without FindControl (e.g. CheckBox_select.<something>).  I thought webforms created all the necessary codebehind from the markup, but it's been a long time since I used it.

Answer (score 4):

```
protected void ImageButton_enable_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow gvrow in GridView_enable.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk1= gvrow.FindControl("CheckBox_select") as CheckBox;
        if (chk1 != null && chk1.Checked == true)
        {
            Label lblEmail = gvrow.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
            if (lblEmail != null)
                 Console.WriteLine(lblEmail.Text);
        }
     }
}
```

**EDIT**
*James' comment compels me to add this:*

The above code change will fix your immediate issue (and when using `FindControl` and methods like it you should always use `as` and check for `null`) but your real problem exists somewhere else. If this chunk of code expects those controls to have been instantiated then you need to look at how they get instanstiated and why they are not when this code executes.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, it just hides the symptom.

Comment: "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statements" this error is showing now in this line "string email = lblEmail.Text;"

Comment: This is because the complier is clever enough to know that declaring a string in a single line block (aka an embedded statement) is pointless. You can never use "email" anywhere else as it goes out of scope immediately. In the spirit of @dkackman's answer just surround that line in braces { } (again this fixes the symptom, not the problem).

Comment: @SantanuMaulik - well you're not doing anything with that string so with the addition of the if block it is a block with only a declaration. So decide to do sometihng with the string and that erro goes away. I'll update the code with something you might want to do.

Comment: actually i will use the email .. i did not finish the code yet.

Comment: @SantanuMaulik well you still need to figure out why one or more of your controls is null or not named the way you think they are. Until you get to the bottom of that you won't end up with an email string, you just won't have an exceptions along the way.

Comment: @dkackman yes i had renamed that control as CheckBox_select1 . i did not noticed that . so it returned "Null" .. thanks btw :)